# Document versioning in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In a project I'm working on I have to take policies written in Microsoft Word and make them into pages of content. One key requirement is that there must be a notion of versioning e.g. Grievance Policy version 2. Further to this users must acknowledge given policy via ticking a box.

So, how I'm approaching this is like so:

- A `Policy` model with a title, content, author and version number which links to a `policies` table
- A `PolicyAcknowledgement` model that acts as a pivot between `User` and `Policy`

Now the part that I can't quite get my head around is the fact that if I'm copying in a 26 page document into a WYSIWYG editor I may save it to find it needs further edits, however this by definition, is not a new version per say as I have not changed any actual content.

So, as much as I could pull in a package that stores model revisions, how would you go about the dilemma which is not every revision is a new version?

**My idea**

In the editing view for a policy, have an extra tick box that says save as a new version, then in the method where you would usually update an existing model, you instead duplicate the model, whilst incrementing the version number.

The shortcomings of this is that if you did need the version history for the sake of compliance you would need a further identifier that pulls all the policy recording together under one grouping.

---

As much as this is a somewhat open question, is what I'm describing revisions with a slight tweak or is there a more practical approach?

Answer (score 1):

Include all the edits so you have a full audit history but have a checkbox, such as "minor edit", that does not update the version number when ticked.